# Шрифт не работает, при подключении через CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты

Собственно, можете указать, в чём ошибка. По какой причине не работает? Браузер - Google Chrome. Пытаюсь вставить на JSFiddle, но ничего не работает.
Как поступить?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "ScarpaLt";
  src: url("/FONTS/ScarpaLt.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
  src: local(ScarpaLt), url("/FONTS/ScarpaLt.ttf"), url("/FONTS/ScarpaLt.woff") format("woff");
}
body {
  background-color: #A9D7D1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "ScarpaLt";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
```

Comment: Вы используете для данных действий, как-то LocalStorage? (метка) Если да, поясните.

Comment: Нет, не использую

Comment: Устанавливайте только метки касающиеся вопроса, так как нерелевантные метки вводят в заблуждение участников сообщества.

Comment: https://transfonter.org/ - сам стили напишет и правильно подключит.

Comment: Зачем два раза src? JsFiddle ничего не знает про ваш шрифт, протестируйте локально, убедитесь, что файлы шрифтов на месте.

Comment: На jsfiddle конечно не будет работать, потому что у него нет файлов шрифтов. Проверяйте на своём сайте и не забудьте загрузить шрифты по правильным адресам

Answer (score -1):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "ScarpaLt";
  src: url("/FONTS/ScarpaLt.eot"); 
  src:
  url("/FONTS/ScarpaLt.ttf") format('truetype'),   
  url("/FONTS/ScarpaLt.woff") format("woff");
}
body {
  background-color: #A9D7D1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "ScarpaLt";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: В чём решение? Можно хоть краткое пояснение. Спасибо!

Comment: Правильно подключил шрифт.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос что-ли, ну почему из каждого надо вытягивать более-менее, хоть какие-то слова. Многие считают, кинул код и всё ок, но это не так, иначе всё было бы существенно проще.

Comment: Можно же написать, подключил шрифты так, потому что... работает так-то и так-то, а вот этот вариант не рабочий потому что так-то

Comment: Пойми меня правильно, тут пока-что не за что плюс поставить.

Comment: Приму на заметку)